# How to use NDsolve for 2D PDE?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I want to solve the following 2D-PDE using NDsolve and plot it, I did:

```
 ClearAll["Global`*"]

 (*Source term*)

 f = E^(-3 t)
  Sin[\[Pi] x] Sin[\[Pi] y] (2 E^(2 t) (-1 + \[Pi]^2) + 
   Sin[\[Pi] x]^2 Sin[\[Pi] y]^2);

 (*Create a Domain*)
  \[CapitalOmega]2D = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];

   dc2 = DirichletCondition[u[x, y, t] == 0, y == 0];
   dc3 = DirichletCondition[u[x, y, t] == 0, y == 1];

   nv2 = NeumannValue[-E^-t \[Pi] Sin[\[Pi] y], x == 0];
   nv3 = NeumannValue[-E^-t \[Pi] Sin[\[Pi] y], x == 1];

   sol = First@
    NDSolve[{D[u[t, x, y], t] == (-(u[t, x, y])^3 + u[t, x, y]) + 
     D[D[u[t, x, y], x], x] + D[D[u[t, x, y], y], y] + f, 
    u[0, x, y] == Sin[\[Pi] x] Sin[\[Pi] y], dc2, dc3, nv2, nv3}, 
    u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 3):

First correct Dirichletconditions, wrong ordered arguments of u!

```
dc2 = DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y ] == 0, y == 0];
dc3 = DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y ] == 0, y == 1];
```

Second correct NeumannValue, these conditions are defined as part of the pde! `MethodOfLines`is able to solve the nonlinear pde (slightly modified)

```
U = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, 
     y] == (-(u[t, x, y])^3 + u[t, x, y]) + 
     Derivative[0, 2, 0][u][t, x, y] + 
     Derivative[0, 0, 2][u][t, x, y] + (E^(-3 t)
       Sin[\[Pi] x] Sin[\[Pi] y] (2 E^(2 t) (-1 + \[Pi]^2) + 
         Sin[\[Pi] x]^2 Sin[\[Pi] y]^2)) + nv2 + nv3 ,
   u[0, x, y] == Sin[\[Pi] x] Sin[\[Pi] y], dc2, dc3}, u, {t, 0, 1}, 
  Element[{x, y}, \[CapitalOmega]2D], 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t , 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}]
```

Check result:

```
Manipulate[Plot3D[U[t, x, y], Element[{x, y}, \[CapitalOmega]2D],PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Mesh -> True], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Neumann, I got:NDSolveValue::femnonlinear: Nonlinear coefficients are not supported in this version of NDSolve.........I used version 11.

Comment: @user62716 What a pity,  Mathematica v12.2 ist able to solve nonlinear pde!

Comment: Thanks, I will try to install it.